# Send SMS form AngularJS Web App

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, sms

I want to send SMS from AngularJS web application. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Please suggest me some reference link or code sample.

Comment: Google: angular sms. 5th result: http://www.123-txt.com/sms-gateway-api/rest-api/sms-api-angular-js-examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique you could use is using Firebase and Zapier to help trigger sending your SMS. You can check out [this blog post which details how to set something like this up](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/sms-notifications-angularjs-firebase-twilio.html).

The trick is loading data into your firebase when you want the SMS to be triggered like this:

```
var sendSMSText = function (recipient) {
var smsQueue = new Firebase('https://.firebaseio.com/sms/' + recipient.phone);
smsQueue.set({
  name: recipient.name,
  phone: recipient.phone
}, onSuccess)
};
```

Then setup Zapier to trigger a new action when an entry is added to your Firebase database. You can have this action trigger a Twilio SMS message.

Hope that helps.

Disclaimer: I work for Twilio.

not working in angular2

Comment: `Firebase` triggers are not supported anymore as of 18 May Google I/O